# How to Determine When a Print Job Completes Using Zebra Android SDK

Tags: java, android, kotlin, zebra-printers, zebra

I'm currently developing an application with the Zebra Android SDK and facing a challenge in determining when a print job has completed on a Zebra printer. I am using the latest version of the Zebra Android SDK.

I attempted to use the sendAndWaitForResponse method in conjunction with the ^HV ZPL command, hoping to receive a "finished" response or similar indication when the print job completes.

However, I didn't receive the expected response. The response was always empty or not indicative of the print job's completion. I suspect this might be due to the specifications of my printer, which operates based on the guidelines provided in Volume One of the ZPL manual. It's possible that the ^HV command or the way I'm using it isn't compatible or sufficient for detecting the end of a print job in my specific scenario.

Comment: Take a look at the `~HS` command.  You will have to poll the printer using the command.  Its return values can be parsed to show current printer status.  Specifically, the `uuuuuuuu - labels remaining in batch` field will go to zero when the label has been printed.    You can also use `~HS` to determine if it is "safe" to send a print job by inspecting the error flags like ribbon out, paper out, head up, etc.

Comment: I managed to make the HS command work, thanks for that. Now I have another question about the sendAndWaitForResponse method: what value should I pass for the terminator parameter? When I use "", the printer just waits until the defined timeout.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `~HS` reply does not have a unique terminator,  It is simply three lines of text, with each line prefixed with `\x02` and ending with `\x03\r\n`.  Not familiar with the android sdk, but can you send the command, then receive the three lines individually?  Most network libraries have "sendline" and "recvline" style interfaces.